# "cannot find symbol" error in IntelliJ IDEA Scratch

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to run some code in a Scratch java file, from IntelliJ IDEA, but once I add a class in my project and try to run it, I get the following error:

```
Error:(1, 45) package com.example does not exist
Error:(11, 9) cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MyClass
  location: class Scratch
```

How can I use my project's classes in a Scratch file?

Answer (score 23):

Make sure the Scratch Run configuraiton has the module, which has these classes defined, specified in **Use classpath of module** drop-down list:
[image]

Comment: Now I get the error "Error:Cannot find associated SDK for run configuration module "com.example.myproject".
Please check project settings."

Comment: The modules drop-down finds several modules, including some I renamed with the old name. I tried all of them, some give the error above, others compile and then when executing say "Error: Could not find or load main class Scratch"

Comment: This feature seems completly buggy to me, I selected a module, erased all my code that used that module, added a simple `System.out.println("THE END");` to test, and the Scratch compiles and executes the old code! It ignores every new modification I make

Comment: Just doing a compile mvn package and then using the Classpath as mentioned above solved my problems.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the required module from the drop down list in **Use classpath of module**(as answered by @Andrey)
2. Now got to **Build** then select **Build Project** or **Rebuild Project**.

These two steps helped me to resolve the issue.Hope it helps you too !